# Actualizar datos desnormalizados en DynamoDB (Coherencia)

Tags: aws, lambda, nosql, eficiencia, dynamodb

Estoy trabajando en una app móvil que utiliza dynamoDB como base de datos, y he desnormalizados algunos datos por términos de rendimiento, utilizo AWS amplify y lo siguiente es un ejemplo del schema graphql donde ser muestra una desnormalización.

Tengo una tabla de usuarios con algunos campos como estos:

```
type User @model @searchable
{
  id: ID!
  userName: String!
  name: String
  phoneNumber: AWSPhone
  email: AWSEmail
  gender: Genders!
  profile: S3Object!
  instagram: String
  webSite: AWSURL
  bio: String
  location: Coordinates
}
```

y una tabla para las publicaciones, por lo tanto en vez de tener una relación (connection) hacia el usuario que subió la publicación evidentemente guardo el id pero también guardo los campos que comúnmente debo mostrar en una publicación.

```
type UserEssential {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  profile: S3Object!
  location: Coordinates
}
type Post @model @searchable
{
  id: ID!
  description: String
  media: [S3Object!]!
  isHidden: Boolean
  userId: ID!
  user: UserEssential
  comments: ...
  likes: ...
}
```

El objetivo de esto es acceder rápidamente a las publicaciones y aprovechar elastic search para esto, pero como dice el titulo la cuestion es, en caso de que el usuario cambie su foto de perfil o nombre, debería actualizar todos los registros donde uso UserEssential (tener en cuenta que lo uso en otros lugares como los modelos Like, Review, Comment) lo que tengo en mente es tener una función lambda que se ejecute mediante Dynamo Streams, es decir, exactamente cuando se actualiza un usuario y luego actualizar todos los post que concuerden con el id del usuario. Realmente no se si es lo mas eficiente o hay otra manera

Answer (score 0):

Una de las posibles soluciones es lo que tu has dicho utilizar un stream dynamo para sincronizar los datos pero ten encuenta que esas lambdas pueden tener errores y que si falla el el evento que genero el error se reintentara por 24h y la lambda quedara bloqueada hasta que se solucione el problema o pasen 24h.

Por otro lado no entiendo porque desnormalizas los datos en dynamo si tienes un elasticsearch, No seria mas util que solo desnormalizaras los datos en elastic? que supongo que es donde consumes los datos?